# Web Service running locally on IIS won't connect to local database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, iis, connection-string

I am new to this, i am facing difficulty in invoking methods of my web service through my browser. When ever I try to insert data into the database it gives me "Database Not Connected" error. I am facing this issue after deploying my web service to the IIS. I have added the connection string as well but still helpless.
I am using SQL SERVER for local database.

P.S I am new here as well so ignore the way i asked question, let me know if im unclear about something .. help in sorting out my problem will be much appreciated

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? What does the connection string look like?

Comment: it is something like "Server=Ahsan-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=OnClickEvents;Integrated Security=true"

Comment: There are so many possibilities here. Posting at the very least some code would go a LONG way to making this question answerable. As it sits right now this is a crap shoot.

Comment: Don't know the possible reason of your problem as little detail is provided. But follow [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis) steps, then may it work

Comment: @MUT thanks it solved my problem :)